# Ranking Discrepancy

Tags: discussion, reputation-leagues

This is more of a "***Huh, that's odd.***" observation than a question.

Currently it is January 12, 2019, and in my little head, I'd expect the month, quarter, and year to date rankings to be equal... but they're not.

- MTD - 798
- QTD - 797
- YTD - 796

Perhaps a quick review of the methodology could be added the to-do list.

> **UPDATE**

I noticed today, that the MTD, QTD and YTD values are consistent.  I suspect AndrewT's observation was correct, and it was a small matter of the sub-sequencing.

Comment: I think *just curious* is more close to `discussion` tag than `bug` tag

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for the direction.  Made the change

Comment: For additional context: as of today, there are 3 other users having the same rep change with you (+395), all placing #795-#798.

Comment: @AndrewT. Great catch!  Then I suspect it is a small matter of sequencing.   Again, this was a small concern and just struck me as odd.

Comment: @AndrewT. Post as an answer so I can accept.  Your insight seems perfectly reasonable to me

Comment: I'd wait for more credible insights (probably from SE devs directly) because even though it's one of the cause, I failed to deduce the real cause for the discrepancy. At least it's not the user ID/age of the account...